# Is every letter in the alphabet in a string at least once?

Tags: php, regex

Was wondering if there was a more efficient way to detect if a string contains every letter in the alphabet one or more times using regex?

I appreciate any suggestions

```
$str = str_split(strtolower('We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize'));

$az = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

$count = 0;
foreach($az as $alph) {
    foreach($str as $z) {
        if($alph == $z) {
           $count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [codereview.se]

Comment: I am not asking for a review of my code, the code works. I am asking for a way to implement this using regex.

Comment: Why using regex?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: There's no real improvement using regex, if you want to improve your code, use `strpos` and break the loop when it returns false.

Comment: I checked the unsupported statement 'A regex is not optimal in this situation." in the answer provided above and found it was #CORRECT by a huge margin. [This test](https://jsperf.com/pangram-loop-vs-regex "This test") shows regex to be >=65% slower.

Comment: `if (!empty(array_diff_key(array_flip(range('a','z')), array_count_values($str)))) {
    echo 'Not all characters are used';
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regex you can do that, but *it isn't optimal nor fast at all*, @hjpotter way if from far faster:

```
var_dump(strlen(preg_replace('~[^a-z]|(.)(?=.*\1)~i', '', $str)) == 26);
```

It removes all non letter characters, all duplicate letters (case insensitive), and compares the string length with 26.

- `[^a-z]` matches any non letter character
- `(.)` captures a letter in group 1
- `(?=.*\1)` checks if the same letter is somewhere else (on the right)
- the i modifier makes the pattern case insensitive

Comment: thank you, can you explain how the regex patterns works, from left to right? :)

Answer (score 5):

Just use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
count(array_diff($az, $str)) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any regex answer. But without regex you can try using PHP's [count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) function.

For example:

```
$test_string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
echo count(count_chars($test_string, 1));
```

Gives you 26 - which is the number of unique chars from $test_string with a frequency greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You current program will print `pangram` for all strings having 26+ alphabets, which means, even `aaa...` is a pangram.

In your inner loop, you can just break if any character from `a-z` is not found:

```
function is_pangram($str) {
  if (strlen($str) < 26) return false; 
  $az = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
  for ($az as $char) {
    if (stripos($str, $char) === false)
      return false;
  return true;
  }
}
```

---

A regex is not optimal in this situation. An alternative approach would be using `array_map` and `str_count`.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, this does not answer the question however and your first assumption about how the code works is incorrect.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend ah, I didn't see the `break` there!

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of Booleans with length 26.  Then you can loop through your string just once.  In pseudo code (because I don't know PHP):

```
Boolean b[26]; // Initialized to false
count = 0;
Loop for each char c in string
   if (not b[c]) then
      ++count;
      b[c] = true
   end
   if (count == 26)
     break;  // All present;
   end
end
// If count < 26 then not all present
```

You need to figure out how to make the character index into the array, but that shouldn't be too hard.